# .exe file won't open after download, unless zipped

Tags: javascript, python, web

Unfortunately this question will be a bit abstract as I have no clue in which scope of development this issue resides.

This .exe file is a python GUI utility that was compiled using pyinstaller, it worked fine as I passed locally to my workmates.

I set up a simple website on our local network to download the file to make it easier, using the following javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Static events
  $(".ui.download.button").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("clickytyclook")
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'UtiliDEA_v2.0.exe';
  });

});
```

Thing is, for some reason the .exe file does not open after downloaded (in my machine it does for some reason), even though it is the same exact file the was shared locally, same size, everything.

But it works normally if I set up to download it zipped.

Comment: It's probably your OS marking it as a file downloaded from the internet, where the extracted version was created by 7zip and came from "your machine." If that's the case, this is also *probably* off-topic for SO.

Comment: @ssube Ah I see, I guess it explains it opening on my machine, but why nothing happens? Shouldn't it trigger smart screen or something?

Comment: @Mojimi Maybe it's because an error is being thrown somewhere that you're not seeing - did you check the developer console or anything like that?

Comment: @Mojimi depends on your OS and anti-virus and everything else (hence being off topic for SO). On my work machine, sometimes downloading an EXE or JAR will succeed but the file will vanish without warning before I can run it. Sometimes it only vanishes once I try to run it. It's always some form of anti-malware causing problems, but the problems vary.

Comment: there really isnt enough info here for anyone to really help you :(

Comment: I really can't give much info because of company rules, but we have shared antivirus, websense, proxy, etc. I guess its some of those, but having it zipped is no big deal

Comment: It's you antivirus wiping that exe silently / repairing it assuming it's infected